# Sending HTTP request in Perl

Tags: windows, perl, http

How can I send a request like this in Perl on Windows?

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Cookie: test=quest
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using sockets:

```
use IO::Socket;
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
                                 PeerAddr => 'www.example.org',
                                 PeerPort => '80',
                                 Proto => 'tcp',
                                );
die "Could not create socket: $!\n" unless $sock;
print $sock "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n";
print $sock "Host: www.example.org\r\n";
print $sock "Cookie: test=quest\r\n\r\n";
print while <$sock>;
close($sock);
```

but you might want to consider using LWP (libwww-perl) instead:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

$req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.example.org/index.html');
$req->header('Cookie' => 'test=quest');

# send request
$res = $ua->request($req);

# check the outcome
if ($res->is_success) { print $res->decoded_content }
else { print "Error: " . $res->status_line . "\n" }
```

You might try reading the [LWP cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl/lwpcook.pod) for an introduction to LWP.

Answer (score 3):

[LWP::UserAgent](http://beta.metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) is the normal starting point. You can pass in an [HTTP::Cookies](http://beta.metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aCookies) object manually if you want to set up specific cookie values in advance.